# My Doctor became a consultant before completing his training and now he won't sit and be taught anymore

Tags: theme-hospital

In Theme Hospital, I have two doctors and a training room.

One doctor is a Consultant Surgeon and the other is just a doctor.

The consultant was training the Doctor to become a surgeon, however, the doctor became a consultant before finishing his surgeon training (it is stuck at 81%).

Now whenever I put the two consultants in the training room (one Surgeon, one not) one of them starts teaching and the other leaves.

How can I make the new consultant complete his surgeon training?

Comment: Wow you just brought back memories. I love this game, havent played it in years though. If I remember correctly this is one of those situations where you have to be tenacious enough to just keep puttin him back in the room until he sits his but down. Another Idea is to just hire a new fledgling doctor and stick his butt in there, why not? New docs are cheap.

Comment: ...that never happened to me, I just can say: good luck!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IIRC - Doctors become consultants when their overall skill reaches a certain level. This skill is increased during any training activity in a classroom. The change to a consultant is otherwise unrelated to their training in additional qualifications (i.e. surgeon, researcher or psychiatrist). If they become a consultant part-way through training one of these skills, they will be forever stuck at the level of training they had when they became a consultant. :(

When a consultant is used for training additional skills, they will only train other doctors in the areas in which they are fully qualified. So your consultant with 81% surgeon training will not be able to teach surgery to another doctor.

Therefore it is best to only train doctors as surgeons / researchers / psychiatrists who have a relatively low skill, so that they can gain their qualifications before they become consultants. Once they have gained their qualifications you can use any consultant to raise their overall skill to the level where they become a consultant themselves, so that they can train others.

Answer (score 0):

Get the doctor with the lowest ability, then train him with a doctor that has 3 skills Surgeon, Physician and Researcher. If a doctor became a consultant it would be impossible to finish his training, this normally happens if his ability is a bit too high... It doesn't matter whatever attitude he has as long as he became a consultant he will became much more faster and efficient...